# remove value from string

Tags: php, regex, string

If I have a string with IDs

```
$myIDs = '22,34,445,67889,23';
```

and I am given a value, how do I remove it from the string, assuming I know for sure it is in the string?

```
$removeID = '445';
```

Do I user preg_replace or is there a better method? For example, if it is in the middle of the string and I remove just a value, I'll end up with two commas and then I need to replace those with a single comma?

```
preg_replace($removeID, '', $myIDs);
```

UPDATE: These are all great suggestions. However, I just thought about one potential issue. This probably need to be handled as an array instead of regex. What is my string looks like this

```
$myIDs = '2312,23,234234';
```

and ID to remove

```
$removeID = '23';
```

There's too many potential matches...

Comment: Regarding your update: Nearly all answers below already considered this possibility. So yes, as shown below, it is definitely possible to do this with regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = explode(',',$myIDs);
$array = array_diff($array,array($removeID));
$output = implode(',',$array);
```

Comment: This is a list of data, therefore the easiest way to manipulate it is with an array!

Comment: This could get inefficient depending on the size of the string.  I'd hate to see something like this done for a string of 100k ids...

Comment: agreed, but it's fine for @santa's data set. There's also the business of a memory/cpu tradeoff between using an array or using a regex.

Comment: @fredley: I was curious, so I whipped up a simple benchmark script.  The array manipulation is about twice as slow as the regex that I came up with.  Def a micro-optimization, but it just shows that it's not really more efficient than a regex (which is cpu bound, where this is memory and cpu bound)...

Comment: @ircmaxell: How long was your test ID string?

Comment: @poke: the given string above.  I've also tested with a 500 element, and it takes 3 times the time of the regex...

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regex:

```
$remove = preg_quote($removeID, '/');
$regex = '/,'.$remove.'$|^'.$remove.',|^'.$remove.'$|,'.$remove.'(?=,)/';
$myIDs = preg_replace($regex, '', $myIDs);
```

Which basically says:  replace `$removeID` where it's prefixed by either the start of the string, or a comma and suffixed by either the end of the string or another comma.

**Edit:** I've changed the regex to a tested regex (I've tested all the possibilities, and it appears to work in all cases I can think of)...

Comment: But doesn't that make `1,2,3` to `13` if `2` is dropped?

Comment: But now it'll leave `,,` in there. (Is this expected?) Maybe instead do `/,RM$|(?<=^|,)RM,/`? Not that nice looking, but that should remove the commas correctly.

Comment: now it doesn't drop the first value, my suggestion is: `$regex = '/(^'.$remove.',|,'.$remove.'(?=,)|(,|^)'.$remove.'$)/';`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regular expression to do the job, for the item "89":

```
/(^|,)89(?=,|$)/
```

It matches ",89" (or just "89" if it's at the beginning of the input), as long as it's followed directly by either another "," or the end of the input.

With proper escaping and some abstraction:

```
<?php
$myIDs = '23,45,678967,89,12';
$toRemove = 89;

$myIDs = preg_replace('/(^|,)' . preg_quote($toRemove) . '(?=,|$)/', '', $myIDs);
?>
```

Tested with multiple inputs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Indeed the string could be in the following formats: '89' OR '1,89,3' OR '1,89' OR '89,3', i.e. can have commas (before|after) or no comma at all.

Comment: @ircmaxell: No. The capture at the end is a lookahead assertion.

Comment: @ircmaxell: Try it out yourself: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$myIDs = '1,2,3,4,5';
$remID = '5';

$myIDs = preg_replace(array("/^$remID,|(?:,|^)$remID$/","/,$remID,/"),
                      array('',','),
                      $myIDs);
```

[Ideone Link](http://www.ideone.com/ppTWu)

Comment: What happens if you have `$myIDs = '1, 2, ,500';`?  you'd wind up with `1,2, ,00`...

Comment: @ircmaxell why that string has to be `'1, 2, ,500'`? I suppose that we are assuming that the string correctly lists numbers divided by commas.

Comment: This is what I was thinking with arrays of patterns and replacements, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Remove the `?` from the first option in the regex.  Otherwise `5` will match `500,10,11`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myarray=explode(',', $myIDs)
$excluded=preg_grep('^' . $removeID . '$', $myarray, PREG_GREP_INVERT)
$newId=join(',', $excluded)
```

Comment: Running a regular expression, on array elements, which basically just checks for equality? This is very inefficient. Using `array_filter` with a simple callback function that just checks for equality would be far better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to throw in a solution as well:

```
preg_replace( '/\b(,' . $rID . '|' . $rID . ',|' . $rID . ')\b/', '', $myIDs );
```

i.e.

```
preg_replace( '/\b(,445|445,|445)\b/', '', $myIDs );
```

([example](http://www.ideone.com/C9GZI))

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is this:

```
$myIDs = '22,34,445,67889,23';
$removeID = 445;

$myIDs = preg_replace("/($removeID,|,$removeID)/", '', $myIDs);
```

**Update**:

```
$myIDs = preg_replace("/(^$removeID,|,$removeID$|,$removeID(?=,))/", '', $myIDs);
```

Comment: Won't work with `$removeID` having the value of `889` for example.

Comment: I like simplicity, but what if the sting has only one ID, therefore no commas?